# Is there a way to determine the weight of different attributes used for R clustering?

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, k-means, hierarchical

I am using ~70 attributes to create clusters using K-means and hierarchical techniques (and maybe ultimately use a blended Hierarchical K-means clustering technique). Is there a way to figure out which ones of the 70 attributes had a greater weight on the final clusters? Or which attributes seem to be more important/polarizing in determining the final clusters? I am running this in R. Thanks!

Comment: If the 70 attributes have different scales (e.g. some vary from 0 to 1000 and some from 0 to 1, then the ones with bigger values will count more. Assuming you standardized the attributes first so they are on equal scale, compute the mean value for each attribute for each group and look at the ranges of the means. Attributes with more variable means across groups are more useful in identifying how the clusters are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [FeatureImpCluster](https://github.com/o1iv3r/FeatureImpCluster):

```
library(FeatureImpCluster)
library(clustMixType)
data <- as.data.table(iris)
res <- kproto(x=data,k=4)

FeatureImp_res <- FeatureImpCluster(res,data)
plot(FeatureImp_res,data,color="type")
```

[image]